# Prose.io is ignoring my _prose.yml file

Tags: hugo, prose

I am using [hugo](http://gohugo.com) and I would like to use it with [prose.io](http://prose.io), as I read here that it is possible to do (in fact, I tested it by forking the repo and works great).

I created a `_prose.yml` file with the following content:

```
prose:
  rooturl: 'content'
  media: 'static/images'
  metadata:
    content/posts:
      - name: "title"
        field:
          element: "text"
          label: "Title"
          placeholder: "Post's title"
      - name: "date"
        field:
          element: "text"
          label: "Fecha"
          placeholder: "Write yyyy-mm-dd"
          value: CURRENT_DATETIME
      - draft:
        field:
          element: "checkbox"
          label: "Draft"
          help: "Unpublish or publish"
          value: true
```

Unfortunately prose.io is ignoring it: I can see all repo's content (not just files inside `content` folder) and I don't see the form for editing metadata.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learnt the hard way that this problem ocurrs when yaml is not well formatted (either indentation or missing field names).  I found where the problem came from: I had to replace `draft:` by `name: "draft"`

Furthermore, I was using a template that uses toml format for metadata instead of yaml.

After converting everything with built-in hugo command `hugo convert toYAML` prose worked just fine.